# How to translate "to make an utterance" in German?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

*Utterance* is translated into German as "Aussage" or "Äußerung". My question is could we say "to make an utterance" like in English or were we supposed to choose another word for that?

> If a person makes an utterance of this sort, we could say she is doing something rather than merely saying something.
>   Wenn eine Person eine Art dieser Äußerung macht, kann man sagen, dass sie etwas tut, anstatt etwas zu sagen.

Comment: I fixed a few minor mistakes not relevant to your question. Also note, that you said "should" (meaning "sollte") in your English sentence, but "kann" (meaning "could") in the German sentence. I changed the English to "could" as it seems to make more sense.

Comment: Em1, Is it not _Kann_ is **Can** and _Könnte_ is **Could**?

Comment: @Em1 But the English sentence was correct…  I'd recommend you revert that edit.

Comment: Oups, right. My bad. Not sure about what's the best English version, perhaps the English sentence should contain "can"; however, the German one is probably best with "können". That being said, if someone is going to revert the English sentence to "should", I think the German one should reflect this with "sollten", though.

Comment: I'd propose to swap *Äußerung* and *Art* in your last sentence: Wenn jemand (less offical sounding than *eine Person*) ein Äußerung dieser Art macht...

Answer (score 1):

You can say *sich äußern*, also z. B. *Gerd äußerte sich zu der Frage, ob ...*.

Comment: Is there a specific position of "sich" in a sentence or it must be side by side with it associated verb like "äußern"? I rewrite it like this: Wenn/falls eine Person sich eine Art dieser Äußerung  äußert,...

Comment: Not necessarily side-by-side; example: _Möchte sich jemand noch zu diesem Tagesordnungspunkt äußern?_

Answer (score 1):

*To make an utterance* could be *sich äußern* or *eine Äußerung/Aussage tätigen* or *eine Äußerung/Aussage von sich geben*.

> Person A makes an utterance
>   Person A äußert sich
>   Person A tätigt eine Äußerung
>   Person A gibt eine Äußerung von sich

In that sense I'd translate your sentence as

> Wenn eine Person sich in dieser Art äußert [or *eine Aussage dieser Art tätigt*], könnte man sagen, dass sie etwas tut, anstatt nur etwas zu sagen.